# create a new column and enter a 1 or 0 based on the conditions provided

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, match

Thanks in advance for any and all help provided.
I have a relatively large data sets and I want to test if each sting exist in a series of subset dataframes that were created from a larger data set.
I am able to accomplish this in three steps but but i would like to write a piece of code that does it in one step.

Because of the size of my files I would like to 
create sub-file t2.a use is to add a 1 or 0 in my file t1, remove it;
then repeat the process for t2.b, t2.c ...

Again thanks

My actual data sets resemble the dataframes below.

```
    t1<- data.frame ( A1 = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown"),
                     A2 = c("orange", "purple", "yellow", "black", NA),
                     A3 = c(1,2,4,5,7))

    t2<- data.frame(B2 = c("black", "pink", "lime", "green", "grey", "mist", "blond", "grass", "violet", "red"),
                    B3 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "d", "a" , "c", "a", "b"))

    > t1
          A1     A2 A3
    1    red orange  1
    2   blue purple  2
    3  green yellow  4
    4 yellow  black  5
    5  brown   <NA>  7
    > t2
           B2 B3
    1   black  a
    2    pink  b
    3    lime  a
    4   green  c
    5    grey  d
    6    mist  d
    7   blond  a
    8   grass  c
    9  violet  a
    10    red  b
```

# My existing code is three steps

```
    # step 1. creates a subset of files 
      for(i in unique(t2$B3)) {
        colName <- paste("t2", i, sep = ".")
        assign(colName, t2[t2$B3==i,])

      }

    # step2. find if string exist in a given subfile
    t1$t2.a<- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.a$B2|t1$A2 %in% t2.a$B2,1,0)
    #
    t1$t2.b<- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.b$B2|t1$A2 %in% t2.b$B2,1,0)
    #
    t1$t2.c<- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.c$B2|t1$A2 %in% t2.c$B2,1,0)
    #
    t1$t2.d<- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.d$B2|t1$A2 %in% t2.d$B2,1,0)

    # 3.remove each newly created data set 
    rm(t2.a)
    rm(t2.b)
    rm(t2.c)
    rm(t2.d) 

    #The result should look like the dataframe below 
       A1     A2 A3 t2.a t2.b t2.c t2.d
    1    red orange  1    0    1    0    0
    2   blue purple  2    0    0    0    0
    3  green yellow  4    0    0    1    0
    4 yellow  black  5    1    0    0    0
    5  brown   <NA>  7    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you made any effort to actually run this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be something off with the `test2` you are printing to the screen:

```
>test2 #OP's test2 printed
      p1    p2 oi NC
1   jaes jelly  1  1
2  tommy   joe  2  1
3    NA    Joe  3  1
4 eleder    NA  4  0
5   food     A  5  0
6  jelly jelly  6  1
```

Based on the data you generated, I feel like there is a difference in the third row.

```
> test2 #test2 based on the provided data
      p1    p2 oi
1   jaes jelly  1
2  tommy   joe  2
3    joe    NA  3
4 eleder    NA  4
5   food     A  5
6  jelly jelly  6
```

Also, I don't see `joe` as a `NM` corresponding to a `D` == `gt` anywhere in `test1`

```
test1[test1$NM == "joe", ]
    D  NM
4  bk joe
12 oo joe
```

Anyways, my overly-complicated solution to allow for `p2` to contribute is below.

```
test2$NC <- ifelse(test2$p1 %in% test1$NM & test2$p2 %in% test1$NM, 
                   ifelse(any(test1$D[which(test1$NM %in% test2$p1)] == "gt") |
                            any(test1$D[which(test1$NM %in% test2$p2)] == "gt"), 1, 0), 0)

> test2
      p1    p2 oi NC
1   jaes jelly  1  1
2  tommy   joe  2  1
3    joe    NA  3  0
4 eleder    NA  4  0
5   food     A  5  0
6  jelly jelly  6  1
```

Note, this will not agree in the third row with your expected output because of the issue I noted above.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind. I want  if a name from test2$p1 or test2$p2 is found in test1$NM, for every instance that it exisits 
in test1$NM, examine each of the coresponding test1$D cells to see if "gt" exist in any of them. 
If for in any of the test1$NM instances the coresponding test1$D cell has "gt", I would like a 1 to be placed the NC column otherwise 0 is placed.
The eisting code seems not to consider the test2$p2 names independently and only seems to cosider the first occurance where the name from test2$p1
shows up in test1$NM, not all the times the name shows up in test1$NM.

Comment: the output should look like this
      p1    p2 oi NC
1   jaes jelly  1  1
2  tommy   joe  2  1
3    joe    NA  3  1
4 eleder    NA  4  0
5   food     A  5  0
6  jelly jelly  6  0

where the 1st gets a 1 bc of jaes of test2$p1 
2nd gets 1 bc of tommy in test2$p1
3rd get 1 bc of joe in test2$p2 
I want to look at all the instaces that the name from either  
test2$p1 or test2$p2 occurs in test1$NM not just the the first occurrence 
and test to see if "gt" exist in corresponding test1$D.

Comment: I apologize, I am not certain if I follow. Do you mind adding the desired column as an output in your original question?